# Liferay Ldap User Authentication Error

Tags: authentication, liferay, openldap

I'm trying to authenticate users from an Ldap server.

Here is my Ldap users :

[image: LDAP]

My admin's path is cn=admin,dc=ldap,dc=agem,dc=com

And here is my liferay authentication settings :

[image]

[image]

[image]

I can connect to my ldap server and i can get users from ldap with test operations.Also restarting liferay several times,users in ldap is copied to liferay that i can see these under users.
But i can not login liferay with this users.I am getting an error like :

`08:32:56,457 ERROR [http-bio-8180-exec-3][LDAPAuth:341] Problem accessing LDAP server
com.liferay.portal.kernel.ldap.LDAPFilterException: Invalid filter cn=agem,cn=admin,dc=ldap,dc=agem,dc=com
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.ldap.LDAPUtil.validateFilter(LDAPUtil.java:285)`

What am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking Liferay code that is giving you the exception ( LDAPUtil.validateFilter) you can see the following code :

```
                if (!filter.startsWith(StringPool.OPEN_PARENTHESIS) ||
                       !filter.endsWith(StringPool.CLOSE_PARENTHESIS)) {

                        return false;
                }
```

So, is the issue you are having, authentication filter needs to start  and end with parenthesis , your filter starts with cn=... . Also, Liferay starts the user search form the base DN, so you should only put in authentication filter the following :  (cn=@screen_name@)  , and not the full DN

Comment: This worked!I thaught that i don't need paranthesis with single filter parameter.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your authentication filter should be somewhat like this

```
(&(objectCategory=inetOrgPerson)(cn=@screen_name@))
```

HTH

Comment: What does objectCategory filter?I can authenticate with only screenName but later i can need this?